# Select category which is not a parent in HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have a table category which has fields and values as shown below in MYSQL database.

```
id  name   parent    sort_order
1   Men    null       0
2   Women  null       1
3   shirt   1         0
4   salwar  2         1
```

I want to write a HQL Query for fetching all categories which is not parent of any other category. I cant slect by using `parent is not null` because i have more number of levels. Here shirts and salwar can be parent when another level comes. How can i do this?

Comment: i guess you mean sth like this? `select * from category c1 where c1.id not in (select c2.id from category c2 where c2.parent = c1.id)`

Comment: @Apostolos Is this the best approach i doubt , and i need hibernate query langauge not sql.

Comment: first of all make sure that this is the query you want. you dont post a query of yours and we're trying to understand if this is the result you want from this query. if indeed this is the correct query, we can see how to transform it to hql.

Comment: @Apostolos `select * from category c1 where c1.id not in (select c2.parent_id from category c2 where c2.parent_id = c1.id)` this is the query i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this hql

```
select c1 from category c1 
where c1.id not in 
(select c2.parent_id from category c2 where c2.parent_id = c1.id)
```